# What is the best way to go about designing a sqaurish clock face?

Tags: inkscape, path

How would I go about making the lines on the clock face?

I am rather inexperienced and have absolutely no idea as to how to do this.

[image]

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use the Pattern Along a Path LPE. What follows isn't a tutorial, just the basics of how to go about it.

Start with a rounded square (using the Polygon tool set to 4 sided) and set up some guides to aid you with the next step

Convert the polygon to a path, add nodes to the guide intersections, and delete the segments in between the guides. You want to end up with something like this

[image]

Then apply the pattern (shown in red) on a path, set to repeated stretched, and increase the spacing.

[image]